# Help with text to Host mom!

Tags: translation, particle-し

I'm a bit confused about parts of a text my host mother sent me, and haven't answered yet because I want to understand what she means completely...

> 楽しんでたよ。公園でやったから、休を働かすゲームもあったしね！

I understand what 楽しい is, and that it can mean "have fun" as 楽しんで, but don't think 楽しんでたよ means the same thing. I know that よ is kind of like ", okay?" but the た threw me off. I wasn't sure about the 休 standing by itself...it seems like it might be a typo. It's hard to tell, since I'm never sure if it's a typo of just something I don't understand. I looked up the 働かす part and figured she meant that she was able to keep the kids busy with with the park and the games.

I know that ゲームもあった means she had games as well, and I know that ね is an ending particle similar to "right?" but the し in front of it confused me a lot.

I'm mostly confused about the んでた in the beginning and the あったしね at the end...particularly the しね part, since I understand the あった.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I understand the main parts of what she's saying, but the parts I don't quite get make it difficult to understand her whole meaning. I guess having it all translated would help me understand, so it isn't all that different. Sorry, I'm just long-winded, I guess.

Comment: Thank you, that really helps a lot!! I guess it was shorter to explain what I didn't understand because it's a small amount. What I know it kind of limited, so I know of ね at the end of sentences, but the し in しね really threw me off.
Similarly, I have seen 楽しんで and know what よ at the end of sentences means, but the で

Comment: *but the だ confused me.

Comment: Can't see any だ you refer to, sorry, I was just trying to explain this way of proceeding makes no sense, it seems I failed.

Comment: No, you didn't fail at all! And that was my mistake, I meant た, but hit the wrong key!
You definitely helped me, so thank you! Sorry, I made it too confusing!!

Comment: We're kind of asking: what parts of the sentence do you understand and how? (Also, is 「休を働かす」 a typo?)

Comment: I tried to explain it a bit above, but I'll try again:

I understand what 楽しい is, and that it can mean "have fun" as 楽しんで, but don't think 楽しんでたよ means the same thing. I know that よ is kind of like ", okay?" but the た threw me off.

I wasn't sure about the 休 standing by itself...it seems like it might be a typo. It's hard to tell, since I'm never sure if it's a typo of just something I don't understand. I looked up the 働かす part and figured she meant that she was able to keep the kids busy with with the park and the games.

Comment: I know that ゲームもあった means she had games as well, and I know that ね is an ending particle similar to "right?" but the し in front of it confused me a lot. 

Hopefully that makes things clear?

Comment: btw, I just made an account in case the change in name was confusing~

Answer (score 1):

> 楽しんでたよ。

means 楽しんで**い**たよ。 "They were having fun."
楽しんで is the te-form of the verb 楽しむ "to enjoy" (or, 楽しん is a conjugated form of the verb 楽しむ and the て is a conjunctive particle/接続助詞).
The い in ～ている/～でいる often gets dropped in casual speech.
The よ at the end is a sentence-final particle (終助詞) that you often use when informing someone of something new.

> 公園でやったから、休を働かすゲームもあったしね！

I think 休を[働]{はたら}かす is a typo for [体]{からだ}を[動]{うご}かす, meaning "to move one's body" "to get physical activity" "to get exercise."
The し is a 接続助詞/conjunctive particle. It has several usages, such as adding information, listing multiple things, giving a reason, etc. Here it means "because," indicating a reason for 楽しんでいたよ. (The から indicates that 公園でやった was the reason for 体を動かすゲームもあった.)
Literally... "Because there were also games in which they had to move their bodies, because they/we did it in the park."
The ね at the end is a sentence-final particle often used when asking for agreement, adding a nuance of "you know," and/or making the sentence sound softer.

Comment: なーんだ、「休」じゃなくて、「体」だったのか…

Comment: OPの文が「休」であることにすら気づかんかった・・・脳が自動的に「体」って読んでた・・・

Comment: I always like to think of よ as being like a spoken exclamation point. And in this case, the speech was transcribed into a text message, so the よ got included there too.